# Mousemove Background Following Y But Not X axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to get my background to follow the mouse and it is successfully working on the Y axis but for some reason won't follow the X axis. Anything suggestions on how I could get the background to follow on the X?

See Fiddle For Example

https://jsfiddle.net/7dkj6beo/

CSS

```
.banner{
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url('http://maxpixel.freegreatpicture.com/static/photo/1x/Graphic-Spotlight-Material-Background-Texture-1988180.jpg');
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 200px 0;
}

h1{
  color: #FFF;
}
```

JS

```
$('.banner').mousemove(function(e){
    var amountMovedX = (e.pageX) / 5;
    var amountMovedY = (e.pageY) / 5;
    $(this).css('background-position', amountMovedX + '% ' + amountMovedY + '%');
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few Minor changes:

```
.banner{
text-align: center;
background-image: url('http://maxpixel.freegreatpicture.com/static/photo/1x/Graphic-Spotlight-Material-Background-Texture-1988180.jpg');
background-position: 50% -20%;
background-size: 120%;
background-attachment: fixed;
padding: 200px;
}
```

And

```
$('.banner').mousemove(function(e){
var amountMovedX = (e.pageX) / 5;
var amountMovedY = (e.pageY) * -3;
$(this).css('background-position', amountMovedX + '% ' + amountMovedY + '%');
});
```

If you go ahead and make the background size 120% and start with a negative Y value for your background position, you can safely go with (X / 5, Y * -2) for your Coordinates and it will follow smoother, just make sure you have a nice high res image.

This will also prevent the edges of your image from showing if someone tilts too far off to the side.

Answer (score 0):

If you omit `background-size: cover`, it will work perfectly. This rule

> scales the background image to be as large as possible so that the background area is completely covered by the background image.

In your case the height of the background-image is displayed fully, so the background-image cannot be moved vertically.